# Minimum permissions needed to run sp_Blitz

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-administration

I need to run sp_Blitz and a bunch of DMV queries from Glenn Berry's Dr DMV set for SQL 2016. The documentation for sp_Blitz on [BrentOzar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/documentation/) states "*Sysadmin permissions. sp_Blitz® checks a lot of system-level diagnostic data.*"

Is sysadmin really the minimum required permission level or has anybody been able to run this with a more restrictive permission level?

Not sure that I am going to get away with asking for sysadmin privilege on a client's production server.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Put it up at : https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well you could certainly modify the proc and remove the stuff that requires sysadmin if you want... But it can't hurt to ask the client. Ask them to create you a temporary account with sysadmin rights so you can perform this specific audit.